# How to split two lines in java ? while i try to split by /n , the string is printing with garbage value :(

Tags: java, selenium

While I tried splite a line by below code. getting the result some garbage. while i printed the value of `selectedproduct.get(j).getText()` I'm getting the below string

```
Civil War A Nation Divided
Playstation2 Software
```

I just required the upper one.

```
System.out.println(selectedproduct.get(j).getText().split("\\n"));
```

Comment: try using `\r\n` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) returns an array of values between each occurrence of the delimiter. The reason you're getting "garbage" values is because arrays use the [default implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) of `toString()`. To print the full array, you can use `Arrays.toString()`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selectedproduct.get(j).getText().split("\\n")));
```

If you only want the first line, just print the first element of the returned array:

```
System.out.println(selectedproduct.get(j).getText().split("\\n")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The .split() would create an array of strings so to get teh first part of splitted array use the index as you print.

```
System.out.println(selectedproduct.get(j).getText().split("\\n")[0]); //index of upper line for you
```

Also in some cases you might want to use `\r\n` for platform specific carriage return -

```
System.out.println(selectedproduct.get(j).getText().split("\\r\\n")[0]);
```